# mundo de conto de fadas ou mundo de contos de fadas

Tags: significado, gramática

Estou com uma dúvida de qual forma é a correta ou a mais correta para a seguinte frase:

1) Ele sempre viveu num **mundo de conto de fadas**.

2) Ele sempre viveu num **mundo de contos de fadas**.

Eu estou inclinado a segunda opção, mas não sei justificar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Complementando a [resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/4844/2764) do Peixoto, eu também diria que ambas as opções são corretas, mas que a opção (1) é preferível. Penso que isso fica mais claro substituindo "de conto de fadas" por "fantasia":

> 1) Ele sempre viveu num **mundo de fantasia**.
>   2) Ele sempre viveu num **mundo de fantasias**.

E eu diria que, com muita atenção ao detalhe, *pode* ser possível atribuir diferentes significados a cada uma das frases.

Na opção (1), entendo que "*de conto de fadas*" mais naturalmente especifica o **tipo** de mundo. Enquanto na opção (2) o "*de conto**s** de fadas*" poderia especificar **de que é feito** esse mundo.

Nesse sentido, em (1) se poderia talvez mais facilmente estar se referindo a um mundo de fantasia, mágico e/ou perfeito, como em

> A princesa, com sua saúde impecável e pais ricos e amorosos, sempre viveu num verdadeiro mundo de conto de fadas (i.e., perfeito).

E em (2), o mundo é constituído de uma série de fantasias, ou seja, outros aspectos, como o do distanciamento da realidade, poderiam estar enfatizados - como em:

> Levada a crer que todos a admiravam e lhe queriam bem, ela sempre viveu num mundo de contos de fadas (i.e., de ilusões).

Mas, de novo, esse "s" aqui é uma diferença muito pequena para, na maior parte dos casos, ser de alguma relevância e, se houver alguma diferença, sua interpretação é altamente subjetiva.

Answer (score 1):

Conto de Fadas é um tipo de história:

> Um conto de fadas é um tipo de história que tipicamente apresenta
>   personagens fantásticos do folclore, como anões, dragões, elfos,
>   fadas, gigantes, gnomos, goblins, grifos, sereias, animais falantes,
>   trolls, unicórnios ou bruxas. A história também, via de regra,
>   apresenta magia ou encantamentos. Contos de fadas se distinguem de
>   outras narrativas folclóricas como as lendas (que, em geral, envolvem
>   a crença na veracidade dos eventos descritos) e as histórias
>   explicitamente morais, incluindo as fábulas. O termo é, sobretudo,
>   utilizado para histórias com origens na tradição europeia e, pelo
>   menos nos séculos recentes, se relaciona em maior parte à literatura
>   infantil.

Fonte: [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contos_de_fadas)

Contos de Fadas seria o plural. Gramaticalmente, ambos estão corretos. Nesse caso específico, acredito que ambos estão corretos. A pessoa pode viver em apenas um conto de fadas ou em vários. Mas se eu fosse utilizar essa expressão, utilizaria no singular.

Answer (score 0):

A opção 1 é a mais adequada "contos de fada". Porque são vários contos elaborados por (uma) fada.

Comment: José, bem-vindo ao site. Eu já vi contos em que há personagens que são fadas, por vezes várias fadas no mesmo conto. Por exemplo, numa das versões da Bela Adormecida que eu li, havia umas quatro fadas. Nunca vi foi um conto elaborado por uma fada. Na verdade nunca vi uma fada. Tens algum exemplo que possas partilhar?